# Why is my nested For loop only returning the first value of the second array when using Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am using a nested For loop to access data in json and then returning a variable to access with Vue on the front end. I am not sure why, but I am only returning the values from the first element of the nested array? Hopefully someone can help with this. It just doesn't seem to make sense.

***There is always only 1 job which is why I am only looping through jobs[0].

I have tried forEach, For of, For, I've tried map (not sure how to implement correctly).

So, this works and I can return the Keys using Vue. Please note this is an example, the json is being accessed correctly and the "Data" needs to be passed to the functions.

```
function getData(Data) {
    var jobs = Jobs;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        return items;
    }
}

try {
    Data.values = getData(Data);
}
catch (e) {
    logError(e);
}
```

Here's the Vue:

```
<div v-for="value in values">{{ value.Key }}</div>
```

This does not work, and I am not sure why?

```
function getData(Data) {
    var jobs = Jobs;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        var items = jobs[0].Items;
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            return items[i].Values;
        }
    }
}

try {
    Data.values = getData(Data);
}
catch (e) {
    logError(e);
}
```

Here's the Vue:

```
<div v-for="value in values">{{ value.Key }}</div>
```

As you can see, I've just gone one layer further into the arrays. However, all I return on the front end is the Key from the first item. I can specify the item I want to access with return items[2].Values for example, so I know I can access them, but I can't get all the Values. The json is formatted correctly, and I've used For loops a million times like this without Vue (I'm newer to Vue) to access the data. Please, before you give me a method, or component, or something Vue specific, understand that I have to use functions like this in a separate js file to return the values that I will be accessing on the front end. It's a weird setup, but it is what it is. I am a bit lost overall but if I could solve this problem it would go a long way because right now I would be using the first example then doing something like this (again just an example):

```
<template v-for="item in items">
<div v-for="value in values">{{ thing.Key }}</div>
</template>
```

That's fine for simple stuff but I'm getting into some issues the further I go down the json. Some of the values I am accessing are 5 and 6 levels deep and there are if statements and I need to do math with some of the values to terun strings and count other items, and there are some items that are objects while other items at the same level of the json are arrays. It's a whole mess and being able to sort it out in the for statements would be really helpful.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you supply a snippet of perhaps a few layers of this nested JSON you're referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is going on but the `getData` function is very suspicious. It sets `jobs` but then enters a loop in which it immediately returns `items`, whatever that is. The loop is equivalent to `if (jobs.length > 0) return items` because if the loop executes even once, it returns (without executing the loop again). And if `jobs.length === 0` then it falls off the bottom of the function and returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring `i` inside both loops. If you're only looping through a single array item for Jobs, you don't need to loop through jobs and jump straight to its items.

You're also return a value so the loop won't pass the first iteration.

```
function getBarCodes(Jobs) {
    var arr = [];
    var items = Jobs[0].Items;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        arr.push(items[i].Values)
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Instead you can loop through items, collect the Values for each item by pushing these to the collection array, and return the array.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense, thank you. What if I needed to go one level or more deeper in the json? Let's say I need to go Jobs -> Items -> Values -> Whatevers? I've used nested forEach and For of loops before to do that but that's not working here so I think staying on your track may work, I'm just not sure the next step.

Comment: Also, I followed this logic for the Values and I am able to console.log the arrays, which I could do before. Still though, nothing shows up on the front end Vue when I use v-for="Value in Values" and {{ Value.Key }} and I have no idea why...

Comment: I should clarify, I was able to console.log the arrays using forEach and For Of loops. The For loop I was trying to use was giving me undefined. Your method works for sure, I just still can't display the output using Vue.

Comment: You'll want to demonstrate, with some code, how you're doing this in Vue since there are number of ways to achieve this.